# Windows GPO printer deployment not appearing for new profiles

Tags: windows, group-policy, shared-printers

Old printers that have always deployed via Print Management > Deploy via GPO are now not deploying for new profiles.

the only Changes have been to my Settings GPO with regard to PrintNightmare and disallowing point and print...
Under Computer>Policies>AdminTemps>Printers>Point and Print Restrictions>

Users can only point and print to these servers> disabled
Users can only point and print to machines in their forest > disabled
When installing drivers for a new connection > show warning and prompt
When updating drivers for an existing connection > show warning and prompt

But New printers do not appear. If I try to deploy the printer via User preferences (instead of the Print management > deploy via GPO) it complains about the driver not being available on the client PC.

Comment: That may be related to the change in default behavior in Point and Print.  See: https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2021-34481  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5005652-manage-new-point-and-print-default-driver-installation-behavior-cve-2021-34481-873642bf-2634-49c5-a23b-6d8e9a302872

Comment: Okay, confirming now. How do i allow users to only install drivers from the official print server in the org? Do i have to change the default policy back?

Comment: If you wanted to back out, add the registry value `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers!PointAndPrintRestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators` to 0 in a GPO. But you also should configured allowed Point and Print servers. Otherwise anyone can escalate to system in a trivial way.

Comment: go make than an answer and i'll mark it. This helped me down the right path to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to back out, add the registry value HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers!PointAndPrintRestrictDriverInstallationToAdministrators to 0 in a GPO. But you also should configured allowed Point and Print servers. Otherwise anyone can escalate to system in a trivial way